# recent-tags is used twice as ID

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, design

In the HTML of THIS web page, `recent-tags` is used twice as a tag ID. Is that allowed in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

yes, I've been meaning to fix that for a while. Thanks for the reminder; fixed.